# Why is Entity Framework inserting duplicating records into table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

For some reason .Net Entity Framework is inserting multiple duplicate records into a table called groups in my database. It seems to be occurring when a user logs in and access group index page.

Here are code snippets of my Index page controller code, as well as the DataContext get method and update method for Groups.

I'm not seeing whats wrong here as I'm only building a model and returning it to Index view. Anyone have any suggestions? I'm using MVC 4, Entity Framework 6.

Screenshot of records: It goes on for 50 rows like this. 
[image]

**Index View Controller**

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Standard, Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        int _userId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        var model = new GroupIndexModel();

        if (Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains("Administrator"))
        {
            ViewBag.Role = "Administrator";
            var modelList = model.BuildIndexModel(_ctx.Groups.GetAllGroups());
            modelList.CampaignTemplates = _ctx.Templates.GetAllCampaignTemplateList();
            modelList.ProcedureTemplates = _ctx.Templates.GetAllProcedureTemplateList(); 

            return View(modelList);

        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Role = "Standard";
            var userGroups = _ctx.ManyToManyRelationShips.GetUserGroups(_userId);
            var modelList = model.BuildIndexModel(_ctx.ManyToManyRelationShips.GetGroupsEntitiesForUser(userGroups));

            foreach( var group in modelList.GroupObjects)
            {
                modelList.CampaignTemplates = _ctx.Templates.GetAllCampaignTemplateList().FindAll(p => p.GroupID == group.GroupId);
            }


            var tempProcTemplateList = _ctx.Templates.GetAllProcedureTemplateList();

            foreach (var cTemplate in modelList.CampaignTemplates)
            {
                modelList.ProcedureTemplates.AddRange(tempProcTemplateList.FindAll(p => p.CampaignTemplateID == cTemplate.CampaignTemplateId));
            }

            return View(modelList);
        }

    }
```

**Groups Manager (Get, GetAll, Add, Update Functions)** 
 public Group Get(int groupId)
        {

```
        try
        {
            var group = new Group();
            var temp = _ctx.Groups.First(p => p.GroupId == groupId);

            if (temp != null)
            {
                group.GroupId = temp.GroupId;
                group.CompanyName = temp.CompanyName;
                group.Email = temp.Email;
                group.PhoneNumber = temp.PhoneNumber;
                group.CreatedDate = temp.CreatedDate;
                group.LastModifiedDate = temp.LastModifiedDate;

            }
            return group;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("An Error occured getting a group", ex);
            // Console.WriteLine("An Error occured getting a group" + System.Environment.NewLine + ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public List<Group> GetAllGroups()
    {
        try
        {
            var groupList = _ctx.Groups.OrderBy(p => p.CompanyName).ToList<Group>();

            return groupList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("An Error occured getting groups", ex);
            //Console.WriteLine("An Error occured getting groups" + System.Environment.NewLine + ex);
            return null;
        }

    }


    public int Add(Group eGroup)
    {
        int newGroupId;

        try
        {
            _ctx.Groups.Add(eGroup);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
            newGroupId = eGroup.GroupId;

            return newGroupId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("An Error occured adding group", ex);
            //Console.WriteLine("An Error occured adding group" + System.Environment.NewLine + ex);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateGroup(Group eGroup)
    {
        try
        {
            var updev = _ctx.Groups.First(p => p.GroupId == eGroup.GroupId);

            if (updev.CompanyName != eGroup.CompanyName)
                updev.CompanyName = eGroup.CompanyName;

            if (updev.Email != eGroup.Email)
                updev.Email = eGroup.Email;

            if (updev.PhoneNumber != eGroup.PhoneNumber)
                updev.PhoneNumber = eGroup.PhoneNumber;

            updev.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

            _ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("An Error occured updating group", ex);
            //  Console.WriteLine("An Error occured updating group" + System.Environment.NewLine + ex);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem seems not to be in this code you posted. I believe it may be in some method you use to fill the object for the Add or Update method. An example of what I mean: User.City = new City("Toronto"); instead of User.CityID = 50; The first would create a new record in City table. I believe the same is happening to you somewhere else in your code. If you are sure it doesn't happen please ignore the comment.

Comment: cool, I will take a look around and see if I'm doing that.

Comment: I looked through my code I have no instances of this type "User.City = new City("Toronto");"

Comment: OK, so disregard my comment. I told so because whenever I see such error I always find such mistake.

Comment: I have the same problem. When my code pass for  **this.Context.SaveChanges();** the record in the DB table is writed two times.